# Reverse engineering python .exe, can not find strings

Tags: reverse-engineering

I started with reverse engineering and using the IDA disassembler tool.
I wrote some programs in C++, made an .exe and reversed it in IDA to "hack" my own programs.

Now I wanted to do the same with a python program. As a start a made this simple program:

```py
inp = input("What is your name?\n")
print("Hi", inp)
```

Then I built an .exe using:

> pyinstaller main.py

Loaded it into IDA and searched for strings. IDA gives me a lot of strings but "What is your name" is not in its list. Why is that?

Comment: Check this https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18041/how-do-you-search-for-unicode-strings

Comment: I checked "Unicode C-style" but still no hits for this search term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `pyinstaller` builds an executable but it is not a "normal" executable. Your Python code is actually in a compressed archive.

```
$ readelf -S main
There are 30 section headers, starting at offset 0x1ad400:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset
       Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000
       0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS         00000000000002a8  000002a8
       000000000000001c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE             00000000000002c4  000002c4
       0000000000000020  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.bu[...] NOTE             00000000000002e4  000002e4
       0000000000000024  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH         0000000000000308  00000308
       0000000000000034  0000000000000000   A       5     0     8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM           0000000000000340  00000340
       00000000000007b0  0000000000000018   A       6     1     8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB           0000000000000af0  00000af0
       0000000000000348  0000000000000000   A       0     0     1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM           0000000000000e38  00000e38
       00000000000000a4  0000000000000002   A       5     0     2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED          0000000000000ee0  00000ee0
       00000000000000a0  0000000000000000   A       6     3     8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA             0000000000000f80  00000f80
       0000000000000198  0000000000000018   A       5     0     8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA             0000000000001118  00001118
       00000000000006d8  0000000000000018  AI       5    24     8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS         0000000000002000  00002000
       0000000000000017  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS         0000000000002020  00002020
       00000000000004a0  0000000000000010  AX       0     0     16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS         00000000000024c0  000024c0
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  AX       0     0     8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS         00000000000024d0  000024d0
       0000000000003f21  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS         00000000000063f4  000063f4
       0000000000000009  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS         0000000000007000  00007000
       0000000000001618  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS         0000000000008618  00008618
       000000000000025c  0000000000000000   A       0     0     4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS         0000000000008878  00008878
       0000000000000e90  0000000000000000   A       0     0     8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       000000000000ad70  00009d70
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       000000000000ad78  00009d78
       0000000000000008  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [21] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS         000000000000ad80  00009d80
       0000000000000040  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [22] .dynamic          DYNAMIC          000000000000adc0  00009dc0
       0000000000000210  0000000000000010  WA       6     0     8
  [23] .got              PROGBITS         000000000000afd0  00009fd0
       0000000000000028  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [24] .got.plt          PROGBITS         000000000000b000  0000a000
       0000000000000260  0000000000000008  WA       0     0     8
  [25] .data             PROGBITS         000000000000b260  0000a260
       0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
  [26] .bss              NOBITS           000000000000b280  0000a270
       00000000000172c0  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
  [27] .comment          PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000a270
       000000000000001c  0000000000000001  MS       0     0     1
  [28] pydata            PROGBITS         0000000000000000  0000a28c
       00000000001a3066  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [29] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  001ad2f2
       000000000000010b  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  l (large), p (processor specific)
$
```

Note the `pydata` section!

You can use `archive_viewer.py` to view the archives in `main`:

```
$ python archive_viewer.py main
 pos, length, uncompressed, iscompressed, type, name
[(0, 215, 285, 1, 'm', 'struct'),
 (215, 1059, 1792, 1, 'm', 'pyimod01_os_path'),
 (1274, 4080, 8938, 1, 'm', 'pyimod02_archive'),
 (5354, 5518, 13005, 1, 'm', 'pyimod03_importers'),
 (10872, 1825, 4051, 1, 's', 'pyiboot01_bootstrap'),
 (12697, 1161, 2135, 1, 's', 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing'),
 (13858, 125, 143, 1, 's', 'main'),
 (13983, 1701919, 1701919, 0, 'z', 'PYZ-00.pyz')]
? x main
to filename? main.x
? q
$ xxd main.x
00000000: e300 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000010: 0003 0000 0040 0000 0073 1600 0000 6500  .....@...s....e.
00000020: 6400 8301 5a01 6502 6401 6501 8302 0100  d...Z.e.d.e.....
00000030: 6402 5300 2903 7a13 5768 6174 2069 7320  d.S.).z.What is 
00000040: 796f 7572 206e 616d 653f 0ada 0248 694e  your name?...HiN
00000050: 2903 da05 696e 7075 74da 0369 6e70 da05  )...input..inp..
00000060: 7072 696e 74a9 0072 0500 0000 7205 0000  print..r....r...
00000070: 007a 076d 6169 6e2e 7079 da08 3c6d 6f64  .z.main.py..<mod
00000080: 756c 653e 0100 0000 7302 0000 0008 01    ule>....s......
$
```

As you can see from the above output the string you are looking for is stored in a compressed archive called `main` which in turn is part of the `main` executable build by `pyinstaller`.