# Where does pyinstaller place my Python bytecode?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using `pyinstaller` to create an executable for my project,

I am using the following code in a file called `my_project.py`,

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QFrame, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent, QObject


class ChildWidgetEventFilter(QObject):

    def eventFilter(self, obj: 'QObject', event: 'QEvent') -> bool:
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            print("ChildWidgetEventFilter: eventFilter")
            return False
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class ChildWidget(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        """
        We need to set our event filter to a variable or it will be garbage collected when we leave
        scope, i.e. self.installEventFilter(ChildWidgetEventFilter()) will not work.
        """
        self._event_filter = ChildWidgetEventFilter()
        self.installEventFilter(self._event_filter)

    def event(self, event: QEvent) -> bool:
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            print("ChildWidget: event")
            return False
        return super().event(event)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("ChildWidget: mousePressEvent")


class ParentWidget(QFrame):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event) -> None:
        print("Inside ParentWidget mousePressEvent")


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main_window = ParentWidget()

layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(ChildWidget("Click me! I'm the child widget"))

main_window.setLayout(layout)

main_window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The command (`pyinstaller my_project.py`) runs smoothly and I can run `my_project.exe`, however, I am trying to understand the structure and cannot seem to find either my original project source code or bytecode version of my project. My understanding is that this is a requirement which the included `python3.dll` will parse and execute my project.

The output contains,

- `PyQt6` Folder and its dependencies
- `_bz2.pyd`
- `_decimal.pyd`
- `_hashlib.pyd`
- `_lzma.pyd`
- `_socket.pyd`
- `_ssl.pyd`
- `base_library.zip`
- `libcrypto-1_1.dll`
- `libssl-1_1.dll`
- `my_project.exe`
- `python3.dll`
- `python310.dll`
- `select.pyd`
- `unicodedata.pyd`
- `VCRUNTIME140.dll`
- `VCRUNTIME140_1.dll`

My question is, where is my original code (or the bytecode) at for it to execute? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyInstaller [embeds compiled Python code](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#python-imports-in-a-bundled-app) (`.pyc` files) within the executable (`my_project.exe`), but not the original source (`.py`). The embedded `.pyc` files can be extracted from the executable using a tool like [PyInstaller Extractor](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor).

Comment: I thought it would only do this when creating a single executable file, not working I did not use --one-file so it was a little surprising.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the `exe` file, but in a compressed form - so you can't just eyeball it. To extract your original code, follow these steps:

1. Run PyInstaller's archive viewer, called `pyi-archive_viewer`, to list the archives of the `exe` file. This will also show you the position of the starting point of each archive.

   - You can read more about the archive structure of a compiled python file here: [Inspecting Archives](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#inspecting-archives).
2. Then when prompted, extract (using `x`) the archive whose name is the name of the main file.

Here's how to run steps 1 and 2 (see another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67848507/reverse-engineering-python-exe-can-not-find-strings)):

```html
$ pyi-archive_viewer my_project.exe

 --> here you'll get the archive names, including my_project.
 --> you're now prompted to extract the content of any archive, so go ahead with:

? x my_project

 --> you're now prompted to output the content to a new file.
 -- go ahead with:

output filename? my_project.x
? q
```

3. You can now open `my_project.x` (`x` is just a dummy extension) using an hex editor, (like [hxd](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)) and see the contents of your original file.